# How to find Windows PCs in an IP range

Tags: c#, network-scan

I want to scan a network and enumerate hostname of all windows machines. There is an interface method that takes an ip range as input and returns hostnames. I have to implement it. So, here is my code:

```
public ICollection<string> EnumerateWindowsComputers(ICollection<string> ipList)
{
    ICollection<string> hostNames = new List<string>();

    foreach (var ip in ipList)
    {
        var hostName = GetHostName(ip);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hostName) == false)
        {
            hostNames.Add(hostName)
        }
    }

    return hostNames;
}

private static string GetHostName(string ipAddress)
{
    try
    {
        IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(ipAddress);
        if (entry != null)
        {
            return entry.HostName;
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + " - " + ipAddress);
    }

    return null;
}
```

This method enumerates all windows machines successfully, but there are network printers in it. I can easily ignore my printers' hostname, but it will not be a good solution. I have to make sure that only the devices with the Windows operating system returned.

Any idea how to do it without a third party library? If there is a better way, we don't have to use `GetHostName` method.

P.S. Linux, MacOS, Android and IOS devices are not found as expected.

Comment: You could check if the `TCP NetBIOS` port is openend,  port 139. (windows filesharing) Why should it be a windows system? what are you looking for? filesharing? specific software to connect to?

Comment: It works, thanks. But I want to ask, what if file sharing port is changed? Is it possible? I have an another method that runs a exe on remote PC (with psexec). I do not want to try unless I'm sure remote machine is Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @Jeroen van Langen's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42666505/how-to-find-windows-pcs-in-an-ip-range#comment72458019_42666505), I changed my `GetHostName` method with `GetWindowsHostName`.

```
private string GetWindowsHostName(string ipAddress)
{
    try
    {
        IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(ipAddress);
        if (entry != null)
        {
            try
            {
                using (TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient())
                {
                    // 445 is default TCP SMB port
                    tcpClient.Connect(ipAddress, 445);
                }

                using (TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient())
                {
                    // 139 is default TCP NetBIOS port.
                    tcpClient.Connect(ipAddress, 139);
                }

                return entry.HostName;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + " - " + ipAddress);
    }

    return null;
}
```

There can be false positive, but this is unlikely and acceptable for me.

Answer (score 0):

Service detection would not be true as there may be linux or other box emulating *Windows FileSharing*

Use `systeminfo /s IPADDRESS` shell command from Windows Machine to reliably fetch remote Windows OS details. You code will be like following:

```
string IPADDRESS = "192.168.1.1";

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

p.startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
p.startInfo.Arguments = "/C systeminfo /s IPADDRESS";
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();

string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();

if(output.Contains("Microsoft Windows")) { Console.WriteLine("Windows OS"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can attempt to detect the OS in a remote machine is through the use of ping. Ping each IP address and get the TTL. That should give you an idea of the OS you're dealing with. A table matching TTL to OS can be found here: http://www.kellyodonnell.com/content/determining-os-type-ping